# refresh list in pull to refresh android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-listview, pull-to-refresh

in native source code of pull_to_refresh library I have to pull the entire height of the layout appears to add a new item to list (see photo).

[image: screenshot]

please tell me where I can change the value of the height which I have to pull to refresh list?
I want to add a new element before I reach for the top of the header layout, for example, 10 pixels
thnx

Comment: which pull_to_refresh library are you using exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the SourceCode, and seeing the parameter `static final float FRICTION = 2.0f;` is hardcoded, so , you can fork the proyect and put a seter for that variable

https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/blob/master/library/src/com/handmark/pulltorefresh/library/PullToRefreshBase.java